# Unable to create action 'hello': The supplied authentication is invalid

Tags: authentication, action, openwhisk

I'm new to openwhisk, trying to create a wsk action,
`wsk action create hello hello.js`
getting the error msg,
 `Unable to create action 'hello': The supplied authentication is invalid` 
what can be the reason? my wsk properties are,

```
client cert     
Client key      
whisk auth      <AUTH_KEY>
whisk API host      openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net
whisk API version   v1
whisk namespace     _
whisk CLI version   2018-07-12T05:26:45.339+0000
whisk API build     2018-08-09T17:17:27Z
whisk API build number  whisk-build-9911
```

Comment: What instructions did you follow to set up the CLI?

Comment: i used this, https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/ansible/README.md

Comment: You seem to be on IBM Cloud Functions (OpenWhisk). Are you aware of https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/bluemix_cli.html#cloudfunctions_cli? Are you logged in to IBM Cloud?

Comment: The API Host should not be `openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net` if you are deploying OpenWhisk on a local machine. Where do you want to use OpenWhisk?

Comment: @JamesThomas yeah the problem should be in the API Host as I manually changed it several times. I deployed OpenWhisk again on gcloud and now it is perfectly working, `whisk API host  35.227.94.111` is my new API host. Thanks for the concern.       CHEERS!!

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration shown, the API host is shown as `openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net`. If you are deploying OpenWhisk locally, this should be the IP address of the local host.